# R error: make: llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory

Tags: r, utf-8

I have RStudio 1.1.419 running on a Mac OS El Capitan. I am trying to install the dplyr package. The installation first attempts to install package utf8. The following is the text I get back:

> - installing *source* package ‘utf8’ ...
>
> ** package ‘utf8’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> ** libs
>
> llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include   -Iutf8lite/src -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c as_utf8.c -o as_utf8.o
>
> make: llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
>
> make: *** [as_utf8.o] Error 1
>
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘utf8’
>
> - removing ‘/Users/andrewdkilmer/Library/R/3.2/library/utf8’
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘utf8’ had non-zero exit status

Since utf8 failed to install, dplyr cannot install either. Why am I getting this 'No such file or directory' error?

Comment: meanwhile, you just close your rstudio and clear temp data from your laptop  and then try to install.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, updated to R version 3.4 and it is working.